# Can "the hat" tessellation be recreated using hexagons marked with "hat" borders and some simple rules?

Tags: tessellations

An aperiodic tiling shape, "the hat" was discovered recently.

If you split a tiled planed into hexagons, containing the borders of the hat, would there be a finite number of unique hexagons.
If so, would there be a simple rule to use said hexagons to recreate the tiled hats?

[image: the hat with hexagons marked]